# Difference between inner_transport_header and transport_header in sk_buff

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

When reading the source code of [sk_buff](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/include/linux/skbuff.h.html#sk_buff), I find the below interesting things:

```
    __u16           inner_transport_header;
    __u16           inner_network_header;
    __u16           inner_mac_header;
    __be16          protocol;
    __u16           transport_header;
    __u16           network_header;
    __u16           mac_header;
```

So what's the difference between `inner_XXXX` and `XXXX` here?

Comment: If my answer is unclear - you can tell what didn't you understand. Otherwise you can mark it as accepted to avoid duplicate questions further.

Comment: Also, what's the reason of forcing [tag:sockets] tag? It has absolutely nothing to do with sockets except the word "socket" in "socket buffer" (`skb`). But there is no relation here with socket API.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `inner_XXXX` fields are used for [protocol encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking)), e.g. [XFRM](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-xfrm.8.html#DESCRIPTION) encryption/decryption.
So `skb` allows to maintain pointers both for original and encapsulating headers.
You always can take a look at [example](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/xfrm4_mode_tunnel.c#L30)s in Linux kernel source code:

```
/* Add encapsulation header.
 *
 * The top IP header will be constructed per RFC 2401.
 */
static int xfrm4_mode_tunnel_output(struct xfrm_state *x, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct dst_entry *dst = skb_dst(skb);
    struct iphdr *top_iph;
    int flags;

    skb_set_inner_network_header(skb, skb_network_offset(skb));
    skb_set_inner_transport_header(skb, skb_transport_offset(skb));

    skb_set_network_header(skb, -x->props.header_len);
    skb->mac_header = skb->network_header +
              offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol);
    skb->transport_header = skb->network_header + sizeof(*top_iph);
    top_iph = ip_hdr(skb);

    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figure it out after asking this question by myself, and I think your answer do get the point but may be you haven't described it perfectly. The difference is obviously, but what's the design thought behind the difference and how we use these two different part is what we need to foucus on. I'm sorry but your answer hasn't show them so I don't give you an acception or useful flag.

Comment: As for the tag socket, why do you think sk_buff have no relationship with socket? The structure socket, sock and __sock_common describe the network socket, and the sk_buff describe the socket buffer, they are related closely. And everyone who wants to learn one of them must learn the other.

Comment: @tyChen One more time: your question has absolutely nothing to do with socket API.
What about `skb`: there could be transit (forward) traffic, such `skb`s has no socket affiliation. Socket API is one big concept, sk_buff is another. The presence of fields in sk_buff structure does not indicate that your question is related to sockets. There are too many different fields in sk_buff, why didn't you add all of them as tags?

Comment: @tyChen *"but what's the design thought behind the difference and how we use these two different part"* - if you know what encapsulation mean you will easily get it. It is used for additional protocols to encapsulate network traffic. *"How we use"* - you don't use it. It's used by someone who want to encapsulate network traffic, one of the famous examples is xfrm, the code snippet of which I added to my answer.

Comment: @red0ct, almost all the examples I see are in the _transmission_ part. Do you how (if at all) the `inner_*` fields are used in the _reception_ part? I'm particularly interested in how they're used when receiving a (VXLAN-encapsulated) overlay packet.